# Trigger script to run when USB drive connected with no user logged on on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mount, backup, udev, usb-drive, automounting

I'm working on a DIY NAS project running on Ubuntu 18.04.

I want to implement the following feature: when an external USB disk is connected (could be a specific disk identified by UUID or PARTITIONUUID or partition volume label, but I could live with 'any disk'), **even if no user is logged on**, a (backup) script is launched.

I've tried various approaches found on the 'net, but none of them works:

- I can't seem to disable the built-in automount, which is required for me to test that my script would run upon disk connection *even if no user is logged on* -- currently I have:

  - the following entry in /etc/fstab:
    PARTUUID=de0528be-7fd9-46f6-b74e-aad68cae11c2   /databackup ext4    defaults,nofail 0   0
  - 'gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount' returns
    'false'

Is the fstab entry causing the automounting? If so, why is that, and I expect this would happen even with no user logged on; how would I then fire the script after the mount has been completed?

- running mount from a script forked by a script launched by a udev rule doesn't work

What am I missing / getting wrong?